# TransactionScope - Problema com Rollback

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, transações

Preciso que o *TransactionScope* faça *Rollback* caso algum desses *foreach* retorne erro.

Adicionei uma *Exception* manualmente entre o 2º e 3º *foreach* para testar se estava funcionando o *rollback*, porém as informações salvas no banco do 1º e 2º *foreach* não foram desfeitas.

Alguém saberia me dizer se está correta essa implementação, e por que o rollback não é feito?

**OBS.: Banco SQL Server**.

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
public static void LancarFinanceiroPedido(List<Contas_Receber> lstContasReceber, List<Recebimentos_Contas_Receber> lstRecebimentos, List<Movimento_Conta> lstMovimentosConta, List<Caixa> lstLancamentosCaixa)
        {
          using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,  new TransactionOptions()
          {
              IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted,
              Timeout = SETCOM_BaseDados.DBTimeout
          })){
                foreach (var item in lstContasReceber)
                    DAO<Contas_Receber>.Create(item);

                foreach (var item in lstRecebimentos)
                    DAO<Recebimentos_Contas_Receber>.Create(item);

                throw new Exception("Exceção proposital para testar o TransactionScope!");

                foreach (var item in lstMovimentosConta)
                    DAO<Movimento_Conta>.Create(item);

                foreach (var item in lstLancamentosCaixa)
                    DAO<Caixa>.Create(item);

                ts.Complete();
            }
        }
```

E um CRUD criado desta forma:

```
public static class DAO<T> where T : class
    {
        public static void Create(T entidade)
        {
            using (var db = new SETCOM_BaseDados())
            {
                db.Set<T>().Add(entidade);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public static void Update(T entidade)
        {
            using (var db = new SETCOM_BaseDados())
            {
                ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entidade, System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public static void Delete(T entidade)
        {
            using (var db = new SETCOM_BaseDados())
            {
                db.Set<T>().Remove(entidade);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public static T Find(object chave)
        {
            using (var db = new SETCOM_BaseDados())
            {
                return db.Set<T>().Find(chave);
            }
        }

        public static List<T> FindAll()
        {
            using (var db = new SETCOM_BaseDados())
            {
                return db.Set<T>().ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Qual o banco de dados que está utilizando?

Comment: Adicionei à pergunta @GabrielHeming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei o problema! Agora o Rollback está funcionando.

Tem tudo a ver com o **TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew** vs **TransactionScopeOption.Required**.

Vejam como ficou a solução:

Meu 1º TransactionScope continuou o mesmo, porém com o parâmetro *RequiresNew*.

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope(**TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew**))
    {
        foreach (var item in lstContasReceber)
            DAO<Contas_Receber>.Create(item);

        foreach (var item in lstRecebimentos)
            DAO<Recebimentos_Contas_Receber>.Create(item);

        throw new Exception("Exceção proposital para testar o TransactionScope!");

        foreach (var item in lstMovimentosConta)
            DAO<Movimento_Conta>.Create(item);

        foreach (var item in lstLancamentosCaixa)
            DAO<Caixa>.Create(item);

        ts.Complete();
    }
```

E em meu CRUD estava apenas faltando um novo *TransactionScope* com o parâmetro **TransactionScopeOption.Required**, pois só assim ele entenderá que a conclusão deste *TransactionScope* interno, é vital para que o 1º seja concluído.

```
public static class DAO<T> where T : class
{
    public static void Create(T entidade)
    {
        using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
        {
            using (var db = new SETCOM_BaseDados())
            {

                db.Set<T>().Add(entidade);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            ts.Complete();
        }
    }
} ...
```